# Date conversion going wrong in as.yearmon

Tags: r, datetime

I have a column as A_Date which has date values with the class as "POSIXct" "POSIXt". Now i have tried to convert these date values into mmm-yy format as date values.

So, I have used as.yearmon() function. After converting i have checked the details. I came to know that for the date values of 01-01-2016 from 12:00 AM to 05:28 AM i am seeing the values as Dec-15 which is wrong.

Comment: Please can you provide the code to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `my_time` is your time in `POSIXct`, do:

`format(my_time, format = "%b-%y")`

If the purpose is simply to round to the first of the month but retain the data type, use this function from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
floor_date(my_time, "month")
```

Comment: If do as you have mentioned. Then if i sort the columns, the sorting happens in alphabetical order rather than calendar order.

Comment: Isn't the purpose of formatting to get a string? Why do you need the formatting then?

If the purpose is simply to round to the first day of the month, see the edit of my answer.